# Serialize list of objects to JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am trying to serialize a list of objects.
   I am making an HTTP API call. The call returns a list of objects (e.g. class A).  I do not have access to the definition of class A.
I tried using dumps

```
print ("Result is: %s", json.dumps(result_list.__dict__))
```

This prints an empty result. However if I were to print the result_list I get below output

```
{
    "ResultList": [{
        "fieldA": 0,
        "fieldB": 1.46903594E9,
        "fieldC": "builder",
        "fieldD": "StringA/StringB-Test-124.35.4.24"
    }]
}
```

IS there a way I can convert the object with whichever field it returns to a json.

Comment: `json.dumps(result_list)` should give you a JSON array (if it is a list)

Comment: There are multiple confusing things of this question, and to me it seems you should re-visit some of the concepts here (classes, objects, json). Anyway, you really want to call `json.dumps()` on the object itself: `json.dumps(result_list)`

Comment: If I try `json.dumps(result_l‌​ist)`, it gives me exception saying result_list is not JSON Seriailizable

Comment: If that's what you get from printing `results_list` it means its a dictionary not a list—and that is why it has no `__dict__`. It also means that `json.dumps(result_list.__dict__)` will raise an `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__'` _not_ produce an empty result as you claim.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify more how the class of which `result_list` is an instance looks like (e.g. post the class code).
`json.dumps(result_list)` probably works not since `result_list` is not a plain dictionary, but an object of a class. You need to dump the variable that holds the data structure (i.e. the same that is displayed in the print call).

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer.